# Can @Nullable be used in place of required=false for a @RequestParam controller method parameter?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

There appear to be two documented ways of marking a parameter of a Spring controller method as optional:

**(1) Add `required=false` to the [`@RequiredParam`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) annotation:**

```
public String books(@RequestParam(name = "category", required = false) String category) {
```

[reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam)

**(2) Change the parameter type to [`Optional<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html):**

```
public String books(@RequestParam(name = "category") Optional<String> category) {
```

[reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-methods)

---

But it appears the following also works:

**(3) Place the [`@Nullable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/lang/Nullable.html) annotation on the parameter:**

```
public String books(@Nullable @RequestParam(name = "category") String category) {
```

---

I prefer #3, but I would feel better about using it if it were documented. I have searched for documentation, but all I can find is what is documented for @Nullable:

> A common Spring annotation to declare that annotated elements can be
>   null under some circumstance.

I cannot find a single example showing `@Nullable` used with `@RequestParam`.

Does anyone know if and where this is documented?

Answer (score 3):

`@Nullable` is a well-known annotation which can be applied to fields, methods, and parameters. Knowing its popularity maybe Spring doesn't mind not mentioning it. So, feel fry to use it.

Now coming to the choice of using validation: I will either go with `@Nullable` or `required = false`.

`Optional<T>` came in java 8 for preventing `NullPointerException`. So, `<Optional<String>` would never give you the `null` value, it would either return the `value` or the `Optional.empty`. And to get the value from this you would need to call an extra method `get()`.

So, if the whole idea is to mark any query paramter as `nullable`, use either `@Nullable` or `required=false`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with not using `Optional` for this. It appears to be widely accepted that `Optional` should not be used for request parameters. In fact, IntelliJ will flag it with a warning. Even so, it makes sense that Spring has chosen to treat it in a reasonable manner. I didn't think of it until reading your answer that using `Optional` does not mean that `required` is switch to `false`. Instead, the value will just never be `false`.

Comment: Yup, as I already mentioned the idea of `Optional` is to make your apllication `null` safe. If this answers your question, kindly accept it as an answer. If you have any other doubts left, feel free to ask.

Comment: Ugh. Too late to edit my comment. I meant to say the value will just never be `null`..